# Dragino lg01-p problem with serial monitor

Tags: serial

i have a dragino lg01-p lora gateway to which i successfully communivate through lora with an arduino and i can program it through network as expected and seen in its manual with the demo client-server code. However, when i try to open the serial monitor on the side of the dragino, i get this:

Unable to connect: retrying (1)...

Unable to connect: retrying (2)...

Unable to connect: retrying (3)...

Unable to connect: retrying (4)...

Unable to connect: is the sketch using the bridge?

I need to have the serial communication cause i made a little app in C# which gets the data from a COM port. I also tried with Console instead of serial, but still didn't get any results back. This is the code, exactly as is in the examples no the manual

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF95 rf95;

int led = A2;
float frequency = 868.0;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // Wait for serial port to be available
  Serial.println("Start Sketch");
  if (!rf95.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");
  // Setup ISM frequency
  rf95.setFrequency(frequency);
  // Setup Power,dBm
  rf95.setTxPower(13);
  // Defaults BW Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/5, Sf = 128chips/symbol, CRC on
  Serial.print("Listening on frequency: ");
  Serial.println(frequency);
}

void loop()
{
  if (rf95.available())
  {
    // Should be a message for us now   
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len))
    {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      RH_RF95::printBuffer("request: ", buf, len);
      Serial.print("got request: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
      Serial.print("RSSI: ");
      Serial.println(rf95.lastRssi(), DEC);
      
      // Send a reply
      uint8_t data[] = "And hello back to you";
      rf95.send(data, sizeof(data));
      rf95.waitPacketSent();
      Serial.println("Sent a reply");
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("recv failed");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it so i will share my problem here to help someone else!

Apparently `Bridge` funcions work better for this device if you include `Process.h` rather than `Bridge.h`.